# how to get an xml in a variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that will return xml. I have delared a variable of type xml and trying to execute the following code

```
 declare @v xml
 set @v = execute get_xml @id, 33
```

whereas id is returned by another query. now it keeps compalinng about the following error
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'execute'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning it make the XML an OUTPUT parameter and call like

```
declare @v xml
execute get_xml @id, 33, @v OUTPUT
```

The definition of the sp will need to be changed as well. example below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_xml2 
@id INT, 
@OtherNumber INT, 
@XML XML = NULL OUTPUT
AS


SET @XML = '<blah />'
```

Comment: my stored proc has only 2 parameters specified. If I execute like you said. it says too many parameters

Comment: You'll need to change the definition of this as well. See edit.